# test if an action it was an update in triggers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I created a trigger for a table when a Delete/Update/Insert action has been made.

to test if it was a delete I use this statement :

```
if exists(select * from deleted)
```

and if it was an insert :

```
if exists(select * from inserted)
```

but how can I test if it was an update

Comment: or you could write simpler logic in 3 separate triggers. This is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SET @action = 'I'; -- Set Action to Insert by default.
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    BEGIN
        SET @action = 
            CASE
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) THEN 'U' -- Set Action to Updated.
                ELSE 'D' -- Set Action to Deleted.       
            END
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) -- New record inserted.
             SET @action = 'I';
    END
```